# Iterate through an NSMutableArray of Objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

I have a class with the following property and method:

header file below - note I did not copy/paste all code (only pertinant information):

```
@interface SQLiteDB : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allAccountsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *accountId, *accountName, *accountDescription, *accountTags, *accountPhoto, *accountCreationDate;

+(id) populateAccountObjectWithId:(NSString *)id andName:(NSString *)name andDescription:(NSString *)description andTags:(NSString *)tags andPhoto:(NSString *)photo andCreationDate:(NSString *)creationDate;

@end
```

implementation file below - note I did not copy/paste all code (only pertinant information):

```
+(id) populateAccountObjectWithId:(NSString *)id andName:(NSString *)name andDescription:(NSString *)description andTags:(NSString *)tags andPhoto:(NSString *)photo andCreationDate:(NSString *)creationDate
{
    SQLiteDB *mySQLiteDB = [[self alloc] init];
    mySQLiteDB.accountId = id;
    mySQLiteDB.accountName = name;
    mySQLiteDB.accountDescription = description;
    mySQLiteDB.accountTags = tags;
    mySQLiteDB.accountPhoto = photo;
    mySQLiteDB.accountCreationDate = creationDate;
    return mySQLiteDB;
}
```

Then, another method in the implementation file fetches all accounts from the SQLite database:

```
-(id) fetchAccountList
{   
    // do some database stuff here
    // create prepared statement, open database, etc...

    allAccountsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *thisAccountId =              [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
        NSString *thisAccountName =            [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSString *thisAccountDescription =     [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        NSString *thisAccountTags =            [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
        NSString *thisAccountPhoto =           [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
        NSString *thisAccountCreationDate =    [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];

        [allAccountsArray addObject:[SQLiteDB populateAccountObjectWithId:thisAccountId andName:thisAccountName andDescription:thisAccountDescription andTags:thisAccountTags andPhoto:thisAccountPhoto andCreationDate:thisAccountCreationDate]];

    }
    // error handling code, etc.
    // finalize, & close code here...

return allAccountsArray;
```

}

Now finally the question. In other classes I want to do stuff with the array of objects that this returns. For instance I would do this in a TableVeiw controller:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    mySQLiteDB = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];
    allAccountsArray = [mySQLiteDB fetchAccountList]; 
}
```

I would use this later to for instance populate the table list in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Perhaps each cell of the table would contain the accountName, accountDescription, and accountCreationDate. I do not however know how to access that name, desc, date from within the array of objects...

This obviously produces an error:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [allAccountsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

because the object at "row" is an "object" containing name, desc, date, etc...

So Stackoverflow, I ask you... How do I accomplish getting the object variables at each element of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
SqliteDB *mySqliteDB = (SQliteDB *)[allAccountsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *myText = mySqliteDB.thisAccountID;
myText = [myText stringByAppendingString:mySqliteDB.thisAccountName];
.... etc.
cell.textLabel.text = myText;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`enumerateObjects:usingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is what you want for iterating, i.e. enumerating, objects. You might have missed it because it's in the superclass.

Comment: Hummm, ok I've never used  enumerateObjects:usingBlock: however will look into it! Thanks for posting! FYI -- I'm about 4 weeks into ever developing anything using Obj C.